# AWS Cognito User Migration Trigger not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

We have two AWS Cognito User Pools, and will be migrating from one to another.  To this end, we have written the following lambda user migration trigger.

Everything works perfectly, except new users are not being created in the new user pool.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

if (event['triggerSource'] == 'UserMigration_Authentication'):

    # lookup the user in consumer1 user pool
    user, msg = authenticateUser(event['userName'], event['request']['password'])

    if user != None:
        event['response']['userAttributes'] = user
        event['response']['finalUserStatus'] = "CONFIRMED"
        event['response']['messageAction'] = "SUPPRESS"
        return event
    else:
        callback("Bad username or password");

elif (event['triggerSource'] == 'UserMigration_ForgotPassword'):
    # lookup the user in consumer1 user pool
    user, msg = authenticateUser(event['userName'], event['request']['password'])

    if user != None:
        event['response']['userAttributes'] = user
        event['response']['finalUserStatus'] = "CONFIRMED"
        event['response']['messageAction'] = "SUPPRESS"
        return event
    else:
        callback("Bad username or password");

else:
    callback('Bad triggerSource' + event['triggerSource']);
```

When running this lambda in test mode, within AWS Console for lambda functions, get the following output:

```
Test Event Name
AuthTest

Response
{
  "version": "1",
  "triggerSource": "UserMigration_Authentication",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "userPoolId": "us-east-1_pe4xVIDEN",
  "userName": "+17202702628",
  "callerContext": {
    "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
    "clientId": "6u7omas12g2m85je4to2hx12"
  },
  "request": {
    "password": "redacted",
    "validationData": null,
    "userAttributes": null
  },
  "response": {
    "userAttributes": [
      {
        "Name": "email_verified",
        "Value": "true"
      },
      {
        "Name": "phone_number_verified",
        "Value": "true"
      },
      {
        "Name": "phone_number",
        "Value": "+17202702628"
      },
      {
        "Name": "given_name",
        "Value": "Randy"
      },
      {
        "Name": "family_name",
        "Value": "Leonard"
      },
      {
        "Name": "email",
        "Value": "rleonard@4thiq.com"
      },
      {
        "Name": "username",
        "Value": "test1234!"
      },
      {
        "Name": "preferred_username",
        "Value": "test1234!"
      }
    ],
    "forceAliasCreation": null,
    "finalUserStatus": "CONFIRMED",
    "messageAction": "SUPPRESS",
    "desiredDeliveryMediums": null
  }
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 18a225d7-72fa-4b84-8199-4ecbd9d4d158 Version: $LATEST
{'version': '1', 'triggerSource': 'UserMigration_Authentication', 'region': 'us-east-1', 'userPoolId': 'us-east-1_pe4xVIDEN', 'userName': '+17202702628', 'callerContext': {'awsSdkVersion': 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown', 'clientId': '6u7omas12g2m85je4to2hx12'}, 'request': {'password': 'P@ssword1', 'validationData': None, 'userAttributes': None}, 'response': {'userAttributes': None, 'forceAliasCreation': None, 'finalUserStatus': None, 'messageAction': None, 'desiredDeliveryMediums': None}}
END RequestId: 18a225d7-72fa-4b84-8199-4ecbd9d4d158
REPORT RequestId: 18a225d7-72fa-4b84-8199-4ecbd9d4d158  Duration: 2542.38 ms    Billed Duration: 2543 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 68 MB  Init Duration: 230.92 ms

Request ID
18a225d7-72fa-4b84-8199-4ecbd9d4d158
```

When running from Cognito's Hosted UI for the new Cognito User Pool, get the same output.  Yet the new user does not appear in the new Cognito User Pool.

Curious what I am missing, feedback is appreciated.

Randy

Comment: Same issue here, haven't been able to find _any_ info online. Did you figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but will need to revisit this soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the format of the `userAttributes` in the response.

Based on the output you share are returning an array of key/value pairs

```
  "response": {
    "userAttributes": [
      {
        "Name": "email_verified",
        "Value": "true"
      },
      // other records here...
    ]
  }
```

According to the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-migrate-user.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-user-migration), the `userAttributes` field should contain key/value pairs.

```
 "response": {
    "userAttributes": {
        "email_verified": true,
        "phone_number_verified": true,
        // other records here...
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I am using the format described in the docs and still I dont get the users created :(

Comment: @RenatoGama it was working for me, but now suddently, i got the error "The username or password you entered is invalid'