# Cognito migration handler returning "Incorrect username or password."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I am trying to implement a basic Cognito migration lambda moving users from Auth0 to Cognito. I am aware there have been many questions on this already. I have reviewed all the questions & answers I think are relevant but have not found a solution. The ones I have looked at are:

- [AWS Cognito User Migration Trigger not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71914069/aws-cognito-user-migration-trigger-not-working)
- [User Migration to Cognito using Lambda trigger in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745219/user-migration-to-cognito-using-lambda-trigger-in-python?rq=4)

I have followed the basic example in the tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-migrate-user.html). Code:

**`index.ts`**

```js
import { Handler, UserMigrationTriggerEvent } from "aws-lambda"
import axios from "axios"
import { Auth0User, Auth0UserInfo} from "./interfaces.js"

function getUserAttributes(user: Auth0UserInfo | Auth0User) {
    return {
        email: user.email,
        // Required for standard migration but also forgotten password
        // flow to enable password-reset code to be sent to user
        email_verified: "true",
        name: user.name,
        given_name: user.given_name,
        family_name: user.family_name,
        updated_at: user.updated_at
    }
}

export const handler: Handler = async (event: UserMigrationTriggerEvent): Promise<UserMigrationTriggerEvent> => {
    try {
        const { AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID, AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_SECRET, AUTH0_TENANT_URL } = process.env

        if (AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID && AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_SECRET && AUTH0_TENANT_URL) {
            if (event.triggerSource === "UserMigration_Authentication" && event.userName && event.request.password) {
                const userInfo = await authenticateWithAuth0AndGetUserInfo(event.userName, event.request.password)
    
                if (userInfo) {
                    console.log(`User Info: ${JSON.stringify(userInfo)}`)

                    event.response.userAttributes = getUserAttributes(userInfo)
                    event.response.finalUserStatus = "CONFIRMED"
                    event.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS"
                }
            } else if (event.triggerSource === "UserMigration_ForgotPassword" && event.userName) {
                const user = await lookupUserWithAuth0(event.userName)

                if (user) {
                    event.response.userAttributes = getUserAttributes(user)
                    event.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS"
                }
            }
        }

        console.log(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`)

        return event
    } catch(err: any) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

Logging out the `event` at the end just to check a valid response which seems correct:

```json
{
    "version": "1",
    "triggerSource": "UserMigration_Authentication",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "userPoolId": "<userPoolId>",
    "userName": "<userName>",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
        "clientId": "<clientId>"
    },
    "request": {
        "password": "<password>",
        "validationData": null,
        "userAttributes": null
    },
    "response": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "email": "<email>",
            "email_verified": "true",
            "name": "<name>",
            "given_name": "<given_name>",
            "family_name": "<family_name>",
            "updated_at": "<updated_at>"
        },
        "forceAliasCreation": null,
        "enableSMSMFA": null,
        "finalUserStatus": "CONFIRMED",
        "messageAction": "SUPPRESS",
        "desiredDeliveryMediums": null
    }
}
```

I have tried `return`ing the `event` or doing `context.succeed` *(now deprecated)* & neither work. The required properties on the user pool *(which are all being populated)* are:

- name
- email
- updated_at

I have also tried altering `email_verified` from a string to a boolean & still doesn't work.

I have attempted adding `username` to the `userAttributes` which shouldn't be required as nothing else is aliased but that doesn't work either.

The app client doesn't have a client secret & it allows the "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH" flow.

Runtime is NodeJS v18.

The Hosted UI always returns:

> "Incorrect username or password"

**EDIT**

I have been reading [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/approaches-for-migrating-users-to-amazon-cognito-user-pools/) as it seems newer. It describes adding the `username` to the `userAttributes` which I have done but still does not work. I have also looked at [this](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-migration-lambda-trigger-errors) troubleshooting guide which recommends to attempt the migrate via the CLI which I have done with:

`aws cognito-idp initiate-auth --client-id <clientId> --auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH --auth-parameters "USERNAME=<username>,PASSWORD=<password>"`

Which gives me the same error:

> An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the InitiateAuth operation: Incorrect username or password.

Passing the `--debug` option doesn't seem to provide anymore insight either.